# How i can find problem with error System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.String' has been registered?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I get error System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.String' has been registered
Project Asp.Net core 6. I run application and i get error.

How can I find out what the problem is?

Stack Trace
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.String' has been registered.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__1(ViewContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator`1.Activate(Object instance, TContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderViewStartsAsync(ViewContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: One of your pages has a `string` argument in the constructor. It probably shouldn't.

Comment: how detect what page?

Comment: Can you share some code about your controller , Program.cs and the class you want to use in controller?